# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '$0.55' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I do not know whats going on but this is my query

```
'$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(price1 as decimal(3,2)))
```

the original output is ***0.55*** now, I want to add the $ sign

my complete query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT x.refno[Reference No.], 
                     Bill = 
                     CASE Z.Which 
                    WHEN '1' THEN cast(y.bill1 as int)
                     WHEN '2' THEN cast(y.bill2 as int)
                     WHEN '3' THEN cast(y.bill3 as int)
                     WHEN '4' THEN cast(y.bill4 as int)
                     WHEN '5' THEN cast(y.bill5 as int)
                    WHEN '6' THEN cast(y.bill6 as int) END, 
                     Rate = 
                     CASE Z.Which
                     WHEN '1' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(price1 as decimal(3,2)))
                      WHEN '2' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(price2 as decimal(3,2)))
                     WHEN '3' THEN  '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(price3 as decimal(3,2)))
                     WHEN '4' THEN  '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(price4 as decimal(3,2)))
                    WHEN '5' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(price1 as decimal(3,2)))
                     WHEN '6' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(price1 as decimal(3,2))) END,
                     Total = CASE Z.Which 
                     WHEN '1' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(ROUND((cast(y.bill1 as int) * price1)/1,3) as decimal(5,2)))
                     WHEN '2' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(ROUND((cast(y.bill2 as int) * price2)/1,3) as decimal(5,2)))
                     WHEN '3' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(ROUND((cast(y.bill3 as int) * price3)/1,3) as decimal(5,2)))
                     WHEN '4' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(ROUND((cast(y.bill4 as int) * price4)/1,3) as decimal(5,2)))
                     WHEN '5' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(ROUND((cast(y.bill5 as int) * price5)/1,3) as decimal(5,2)))
                     WHEN '6' THEN '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),cast(ROUND((cast(y.bill6 as int) * price6)/1,3) as decimal(5,2))) END 
                     FROM 
                    trans Y
                    INNER JOIN projects X on  X.refno = y.refno
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT '1'  union ALL SELECT '2' UNION ALL  SELECT '3' UNION ALL  SELECT '4' UNION ALL  SELECT '5' UNION  ALL SELECT '6') Z (Which) 
                    WHERE y.refno in ('test1')) TMP_TAB
                    WHERE Rate <> 0 AND Bill <> 0  ORDER by TMP_TAB.[Reference No.]
```

Comment: This statement is fine, the issue caused by another part of the query.

Comment: Maybe try putting a SELECT in front of that?

Comment: There is no conversion to "int" in this part of the query.  This statement cannot be causing that error.

Comment: Post your complete query.

Comment: I updated my question @Raj

Comment: `price1` and `price2` and so on should be from 0 to 9 as int to be able to convert to `decimal(3,2)` ;).

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culprit

```
WHERE Rate <> 0 AND Bill <> 0  ORDER by TMP_TAB.[Reference No.]
```

`TMP_TAB` is a derived table where the value of `Rate` is `$0.55`. In the above `WHERE` clause, you are trying to check if it is not equal to zero. SQL is trying to convert `$0.55` to `int` and throwing this error.

You might want to try

```
WHERE Rate <> '$0.00' AND Bill <> 0  ORDER by TMP_TAB.[Reference No.]
```